# Spottin outside ProTools

Tags: sound-editing

Dear sound Designers,
I need to know if exist a way, using softwares like soundminers, basehead or similiar, to spot a region outside pro tools and drag it at the beginning or at the end of an audio file storaged in a network hard disk.
I need the opposite feature of spotting audio into a daw because my need is to update files with new regions recorded and do that on the fly!
Thanks for the answers,
Bye
Giorgio

Answer (score 1):

I use "Audiofinder". Its an amazing librarian / processing tool, and it spots to Pro Tools. Give the demo a trial.

http://www.icedaudio.com/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I don't think this is possible. You can drag regions from the timeline or region bin to the structure sampler an avid / digi virtual instrument plugin. That's the only time I've seen dragging anything from pro tools to another application. Are you ware that you can export regions from pro tools as audio files ??

Comment: yes I have to export audio but in the same time quickly update an audio file in a network hard disk, putting the exported audio file at the beginning on in the end of that file....

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure I entiiirely understand what you're asking. But, if you're looking to add some audio to the start/end of a bunch of already recorded audio files then perhaps using some kind of audio editor with batch processing might be worth looking at?